# How to Customize Multi language on Multi domain in Typo3?

Tags: typo3, multilingual

I have Four language enabled i.e German,french,Russian,Chinese and English is the default one.My site is in Two domain what i want to do is For Second Domain I dont want this all language Available Only During Content addition.Specific Language must be listed.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the languages a editor can use within a page tree by adding some PageTSConfig to the root page of the pageTree:

```
mod.SHARED {
   # Change the Flag for default content (sys_langauge_uid=0)
   defaultLanguageFlag = fr
   # Change the Label for default content (sys_langauge_uid=0)
   defaultLanguageLabel = Francaise
   # Disable languages for editors
   disableLanguages = 1,4
}
```